# Search string per line in a text file. If found save all lines to another text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Just like to create a batch script.  I have a text file with multiple lines. Need to search a string per line and if found save that whole line to another text file.  All lines with the string will be saved into a new text file.

**Input:**

```
abcdefgh

ghabcdef

;

ghijklmno

.

defghabc
```

**Preferred output:**

```
abcdefgh

ghabcdef

defghabc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Fine... and what is your question? "I need..." is not a question but a task request. Are you really working with MS-DOS, the 1980s OS?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the interest.  I cannot make a DOS script that can search a specific string in text file with multiple lines.  The script needs to search each line. If the string is found, that particular line should be copied to another text file. all lines with the string required should be placed in one new text file.  I hope somebody in this forum can help me create that script.  I can use it in a different situation like segregating set of searched string into different text files. Thanks,

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) and [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) are your friends. The referenced pages are for `cmd`, but as far as I remember neither `find` nor redirection changed much since DOS.

Comment: See `findstr /?`. `Findstr /c:"string" <inputfile >outputfile`

Comment: @Noodles `findstr` is not available in DOS.[find](http://www.computerhope.com/findhlp.htm) is.

Comment: It's available on Dos 5.5 (the Dos in 32 bit Windows). All NT commands are available on Dos 5.5.

Comment: @Noodles There's no such thing as DOS 5.5. NTVDM, the MS-DOS emulator builtin to 32-bit versions of the NT based versions of Windows, doesn't have its own version number. It's also extremely unlikely the original poster is using it. There's no reason to use NTVDM to run batch scripts on Windows. The OP is either using Windows command prompt (`cmd`) or a real version of MS-DOS. Probably the former.

Comment: operating system is Windows 7 Pro... am using .bat files for this script.. am not very good at this.. just trying to automate a few file handling stuff.. i tried using findstr but i think my syntax is incorrect.. I've tried searching for similar cases here in stackoverflow.. but cant find one.. hope somebody can help me on this.. thanks!

Comment: I'm sure we can help you, if you show us your code and explain us , how it doesn't work.

Comment: seems to me that this is a case for `grep`...

Comment: @ross ridge Type in any Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista/7 32 bit `command /c ver`. It says Dos 5.5.

Comment: @Noodles Nope. When I enter "ver" after running `command`, it says "Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]"

Comment: I didn't say to do that. Anything typed in command is sent to cmd for execution (how 5.5 differs from Dos 5). Type `command /c ver`.

Comment: appreciate replies of the community... Initially I've tried to focus on using findstr command to provide me with the list I need.. then I tried using find command and it works with a help of for loop.

Comment: find "abc" myfile.txt >myfile.tmp 
FOR /F "skip=2 delims=" %%i in (myfile.tmp) do @echo %%i >> lsfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

(from your comment):

```
find "abc" myfile.txt >myfile.tmp 
FOR /F "skip=2 delims=" %%i in (myfile.tmp) do @echo %%i >> lsfile.txt
```

But you don't need `for` and a temp file. `find` doesn't write a header, when it parses STDIN. To do so, you can:

```
type myfile.txt | find "abc" >lsfile.txt
```